# Polymorphic HashTable like datastructure

Tags: data-structures, polymorphism, hashtable

I'm creating a client side cache object and one of the consumers of the cache needs a means of looking up data by type.  Obviously I can't just have a map from class to data since that wouldn't retrieve subtypes of the class.  Is there a 'standard' or well suited data structure for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a HashTable, it'd be easier to use a tree, since a tree would easily represent the type heirarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If you key you HashMap by Class objects it will behave exactly as you expect it to. There will be no lookup on "subtype".

Comment: Right, but it's the inclusion of subtypes that I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Right, not with any of the standard implementations of the Map interface.